# Usefulness of HashMaps in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

So I was working on a programming challenge where I wanted to store more than 128 key-value pairs of type `<int, int>.`

Since HashMaps can't accept primitives, I used `<Integer, Integer`>.  I ran into a problem where I'd go:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
Integer x = new Integer(130);
map.put(x, x);
```

Later on in my code, I compute the value I need to retrieve from the map as an integer. I try to retrieve it using:

```
int calculated = 130;
Integer y = new Integer(calculated);
map.get(y)
```

This will cause a NullPointerException because the HashCode of the x and y are different (which is expected because the Integer class keeps a cache of values only between -128 and 127).

My question is if I want to store a large number of key-value pairs using a map-like structure in Java, how would I do so?

[EDIT]:  Thank you everyone for your responses!  After having refactored some of my logic, the problem no longer exists (it wasn't a problem with the Integer itself).  Thanks for making me appreciate using HashMaps in Java again :)

Comment: I think there is no need to do Integer y = new Integer(calculated); because outboxing and inboxing in Java. Integer y = 130; is enough

Comment: Where are you getting an NPE?. Unless you are doing something else, you can't get NPE.

Comment: Can't get `NPE` here. Post your complete code.

Comment: `This will cause a NullPointerException because the HashCode of the x and y are different...` The contract of `hashcode()` requires that if `x.equals(y)` returns `true`, then `x.hashcode() == y.hashcode()` is also `true`.

Comment: @RahinJegarajaratnam The NullPointerException is caused by something else. See my previous comment.

Comment: @RahinJegarajaratnam could you please explain what you mean by hashcode is not cached?

Comment: @RahinJegarajaratnam Where you get `NPE`?http://ideone.com/tzWxsr

Comment: @RahinJegarajaratnam - The hashCode of an Integer is its value. What has *caching* got to do with this?

Comment: If you look at the source of Integer you will find that the hashcode is just the integer value. The hash code of two different Integer objects with the same value should be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This will cause a NullPointerException because the HashCode of the x and y are different (which is expected because the Integer class keeps a cache of values only between -128 and 127).

That's irrelevant. `Integer` overrides `hashCode()` and `equals()` appropriately, which is all that's required for non-identical objects to be looked up in a `HashMap`. (The hash codes of two equal `Integer` values will be the same, even if they're not the same `Integer` objects.)

It should be absolutely fine:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
Integer x = 130;
Integer y = 130;
System.out.println(x == y); // False (on my machine)
map.put(x, 1000);
System.out.println(map.get(y)); // 1000
```

Additionally, just the statement `map.get(y)` will not throw a `NullPointerException` unless `map` or `y` is `null`... even if it can't find a match, it will return `null`, not throw an exception.

Note that you don't need to call `new Integer(...)` - and if you do, the caching for boxed values is irrelevant anyway. For example:

```
Integer a = new Integer(5);
Integer b = new Integer(5);
System.out.println(a == b); // False, always

Integer c = 5;
Integer d = 5;
System.out.println(c == d); // True, always, due to caching of small boxed values
```

Comment: in here map.put(x, 1000); where 1000 came from? :)

Comment: @KickButtowski: It's a value I just used to differentiate between the value in the entry and the key. While I could have used `map.put(x, x)` it felt simpler to use a different value - that way it's obvious what's being looked up.

Comment: @KickButtowski that is not relevant

Comment: May I ask why you did not use same value?

Comment: +1 for your nice explanation sir :)

Comment: @KickButtowski you can write a code and check yourself is there any difference with `(x,x)`,http://ideone.com/tzWxsr

Comment: To add to *Jon's* (as always) exceptional answer. In the second code block, When you do `Integer i = 5;` it will be converted to `Integer i = Integer.valueOf(5)`. The `valueOf()` method uses a local cache. So the second case is true. `new Integer()` doesn't use the local cache, so the first case is false.

Answer (score -1):

> This will cause a NullPointerException

No it won't, unless 'map' is null.

> because the HashCode of the x and y are different

No they aren't.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Lundin Certainly it does. It tells the OP that he is mistaken in his conclusions, and provides an alternative explanation.

Comment: "My question is if I want to store a large number of key-value pairs using a map-like structure in Java, how would I do so?" Your post doesn't attempt to answer the question. If the question is incorrect, lacks information or cannot be answered in its current shape, then advise the OP about this through comments, not by posting an answer.

Comment: @Lundin You're not making sense. 'How would I do so' is with a Map, which is what you're already doing. Your *actual* question is about the NPE, which arises from different causes from what you imagined, and which is all that is addressed by both this answer and the answer you've accepted.